# Problema con un bucle while

Tags: java

Buenas, dado el siguiente código, resutla que aunque escriba como alto -1 y como ancho 30, sigue ejecutándose código y me saldría, en este ejemplo, lo último.

Quiero saber cómo prohibir el menor que 1 y el mayor que 20 para que no se ejecute el código, lo suyo sería hacerlo con for, pero me vale con un while y luego lo transformo en for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */


public class Ejercicio6_2Try {
public static int alto;
public static int ancho;
public static String guiones = "-";
public static String asteriscos ="*";
public static String rectangulo, altorectangulo, espaciostotal;
public static String espacios =" ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//for (;((alto>1) || (alto<20) ) && ((ancho>1) || (ancho<20));){

while ((alto <= 1) || (ancho <= 1) || (alto > 20) || (ancho > 20)){

try

    {


            System.out.println("Escribe el alto del marco, entre 1 y 20");
            alto = sc.nextInt();
            int i = alto;

            System.out.println("Escribe el ancho del marco, entre 1 y 20");
            ancho = sc.nextInt();

            switch (alto){
            case 1:

            switch (ancho) {
                case 1:
                    rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
                    System.out.println("+");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
                    System.out.println("++");
                    break;
                default:
                    rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
                    System.out.println("+" + rectangulo + "+");
                    break;                
            }

            break;

            case 2:


            break;

            case 3:

            break;

            case 4:

            break;

            case 5:

            break;            

            default:
        rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
        System.out.println("+" + rectangulo + "+");
        altorectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", asteriscos);
        System.out.println("|" + altorectangulo + "|"); 

            for (;((i>4) && (i<=20) && (ancho<=20));){
            i--;

        espaciostotal = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", espacios);
        System.out.println("|" + espaciostotal + "|");

        }

        altorectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", asteriscos);
        System.out.println("|" + altorectangulo + "|");             
        rectangulo = new String(new char[ancho]).replace("\0", guiones);
        System.out.println("+" + rectangulo + "+");            



            }
            }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Has introducido un valor incorrecto");
        sc.nextLine();
    }

}
}
}
```

Esta es la salida de código con -1 30, y no tendría que salir nada porque si se ejecuta solo cuando es mayor:

```
run:
Escribe el alto del marco, entre 1 y 20
-1
Escribe el ancho del marco, entre 1 y 20
30
+------------------------------+
|******************************|
|******************************|
+------------------------------+
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: podria colocar un ejemplo que si se ejecute correctamente, es decir que imprima de acorde a los datos de entrada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a inicializar las variables

```
        System.out.println("Escribe el alto del marco, entre 1 y 20");
        alto = sc.nextInt();
        int i = alto;

        System.out.println("Escribe el ancho del marco, entre 1 y 20");
        ancho = sc.nextInt();
```

fuera del bucle while().
Declaralos antes de entrar al while

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un `do while` antes de los `switch statements`

```
do {
    System.out.println("Escribe el alto del marco, entre 1 y 20");
    alto = sc.nextInt();
    int i = alto;

    System.out.println("Escribe el ancho del marco, entre 1 y 20");
    ancho = sc.nextInt();
 }while ((alto <= 1) || (ancho <= 1) || (alto > 20) || (ancho > 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu bucle White tiene mal las condiciones ya que estas permitiendo entrar, además de antes de declarar los valores para las variables(debes declarar los input antes de la comprobación del White.

//primero declara y recoge las entradas por teclado aquí

//ahora poner la condición para entrar en el bucle, que es cuando los valores sean entre 1 y 20. Poniendo ! Delante de la variable es como negar(mientras alto No sea menor que 1...y así. 
while ((!alto <1) || (!ancho < 1) || (!alto > 20) || (!ancho > 20)){
//otra opción es cambiar todos los signos porque los declarase al revés. 
//while ((alto >=1) || (ancho >=1) || (alto < 20) || (ancho<20))
//aquí dentro pones todo lo que se ejecuta cuando se cumple alguna de las condiciones de arriba

} 
//fuera del bucle el mensaje de error.

Si estás empezando te recomiendo hacer debug de tu código usando 
System.out.println("texto a imprimir por pantalla") ;
Entre líneas del código, para saber en qué bucles ha entrado y en cuáles no. Sobretodo si trabajas con bucles condicionales y no dominas aún esos parámetros.

Lo mejor para aprender es encontrar los fallos uno mismo aunque sea picando piedras.! Suerte espero que te funcione